Wizard Dip Spell Recording
Similar questions have been asked, but this has not been answered (please point me to it if I’m mistaken):
A leveled Sorcerer (for the sake of argument, Sorc 5) takes a 1-2 level dip in Wizard. From Wizard:

“Copying a Spell into the Book. When you find a wizard spell of 1st level or higher, you can add it to your spellbook if it is of a spell level you can prepare and if you can spare the time to decipher and copy it.


Copying a spell into your spellbook involves reproducing the basic form of the spell, then deciphering the unique system of notation used by the wizard who wrote it. You must practice the spell until you understand the sounds or gestures required, then transcribe it into your spellbook using your own notation.”

The first paragraph indicates that a spell has to be found. The latter implies that if you’re already able to cast spells (as a sorcerer) that you could otherwise prepare (as a wizard), you could reasonably copy the applicable (level one) spells into your spell book for the requisite costs. Additionally these would reasonably be the reduced costs of copying below since you are the originating mage.

” This is just like copying a new spell into your spellbook, but faster and easier, since you understand your own notation and already know how to cast the spell. You need spend only 1 hour and 10 gp for each level of the copied spell.

This would mean that a sorcerer could, upon learning wizard-craft, record all of their first level spells (for which they now understand the academic arcane progression). Then, during subsequent level-ups, forget and free up those spells known and use that mental space to expand their sorceries to higher level spells, all without actually forgetting any first level spells. From Sorcerer:

“Additionally, when you gain a level in this class, you can choose one of the sorcerer spells you know and replace it with another spell from the sorcerer spell list, which also must be of a level for which you have spell slots.”

Am I missing anything or is this interpretation accurate? It doesn’t seem contrary to RAW since the class entries don’t cover multiclass but do address spells you know how to cast being put into a spell book.

The context leading up to the quotation "This is just like copying a new spell..." seems very relevant.  What does that say?

It refers to copying your own spell book, which is cheaper because of  your familiarity with the spell and your own notation.

No.
A little preface; at one point, you say the word "indicates," because the text actually says that. In the next point, you say "implies." The change in diction supports the fundamental difference I'm about to highlight.
Implication is the ally of RAI, but it is the enemy of RAW. When things in the rules are 'implied,' it is explicitly because they are not written, and therefore cannot be RAW without a Sage Advice Compendium update - of which there are unlikely to be anymore now that 2024 is out.
Preface over
Let's discuss some phrases that get thrown around a lot in magic. "Spell List," "Spellcasting Class," and "(insert class name here with a capital letter) Spell."
There are some intriguing rules interactions around some of these phrases; for example, when you play a dragonmarked subrace from the Eberron books, the table of spells are added to the spell list of your spellcasting class. This means if your subrace spell list gives you healing spells, and you're a wizard, those healing spells are now on the wizard spell list for you, and you can go get a scroll of them to copy, or learn them during a level-up if you have high enough slots.
This leads me into the transition that answers your question. When you know a spell as a sorcerer spell, that spell also being on the wizard spell list does not make it a wizard spell for you, because you have not yet learned that spell as a wizard spell- thus the reason you could only cast it with Charisma but not Intelligence until it's also in your book.
And if you'll notice, the second sentence of your first quote (the part about Copying a Spell, which is later brought up as "This is just like copying a new spell," in your premise) reads-

"When you find a wizard spell."

So your sorcerer's magic missile is only a sorcerer's magic missile, until you study it per your wizard feature from a scroll, or a with a wizard spell acquired during level-up.
And it's important to remember that if you do swap out the Sorcerer spell after acquiring it as a Wizard Spell, you'll no longer be able to cast that spell with Charisma, as the Spellcasting Feature granted by wizard to which the spell belongs for you doesn't allow you to cast its spells with anything but Intelligence.
Finally, I probably should've started with this, but I personally haven't played a sorcerer in 5e so I didn't even realize it until I went back to check, but the ability specifies prepared spells. While known spells are always fixed in mind and able to be cast, the rules text explicitly goes out of its way to separate "known" spells, like the kind bards and sorcerers get, and prepared spells, like the kind wizards and clerics get. Sorcerer spells are not prepared; they are known, always castable/fixed in the caster's mind.

This correct answer could be improved by citing the multiclass rules on spellcasting.

Thank you, aspects of this were good clarification. However, I’m not convinced of its accuracy. As you said, a spell that is a wizard spell ‘for you’ (the anecdote about healing spells notwithstanding) does not need to be known to you at the time of transcription; that’s the point of transcription. You can very well ‘find’ the spell in yourself, that doesn’t mean you know it as a wizard spell. The text states that the purpose of transcription is to understand and record aspects of a spell (sounds and gestures) that you will already grasp as a sorcerer spell.

Of note, RAW you can transcribe prepared spells to a new spell book (from your own familiarity, notation not required) in the case you lose your spell book.

That specifies that you can copy from your spell book.  It certainly doesn't say "notation not required," only that you "know your own notation" -- from your spell book.

If spell book is lost, you can copy prepared spells (i.e. from your mind) to a new spell book. This is explicitly stated in the section regarding copying.

@D20Machine The paragraph before the one you're quoting is very important. It involves copying a spell from your own spellbook, (i.e. wizard notation/spell, explicitly) and is about replacing a spellbook. The sentence that you're paraphrasing actually reads "If you lose your spellbook, you can use the same procedure to transcribe the spells you have prepared into a new spellbook."   <--- That's a wizard feature for wizard spells that you can cast after preparing them from a spellbook. I don't see text explicitly giving permission to turn a sorcerer spell into a wizard spell.

@JoelHarmon I often have a problem with running on, and that's a lot of citation. I tried to hit the most relevant points. Which ones in particular would you say I should add, or should I just go for the entire section and slap TLDRs on both sides? :D
